# Toggle Checkbox Data Binding In Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to send value using a toggle switch checkbox value as Hourly or Salary. How can i bind in the below form.

**html**

```html
            <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="can-toggle">
                                <input id="a" type="checkbox">
                                <label for="a">
                                    <div class="can-toggle__switch" data-checked="Salary" formControlName="payType" data-unchecked="Hourly"></div>
                                </label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
 payType = new FormControl(true, [Validators.required]);
        model.payType = createForm.payType;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below code. It will fulfil your requirement.

**your.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="can-toggle">
          <input id="a" type="checkbox" formControlName="payType" />
          <label for="a">
            <div class="can-toggle__switch">{{myForm.controls['payType'].value ? "Salary" : "Hourly"}}</div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**your.component.ts**

```
myForm: FormGroup;
constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      payType: new FormControl(false)
    })
}

onSubmit(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The requirement feels like customising default value for checkbox. You can go ahead and write your own checkbox logic that accepts value for `true` (checked) and `false` (unchecked) state.

Read angular documentation for [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) to get more details.

Here is an example (check it on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bct398?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/custom-checkbox/custom-checkbox.component.ts))

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <app-custom-checkbox
      [checkedValue]="checked"
      [unCheckedValue]="unChecked"
      [formControl]="formControl"
    >
      {{ checked }}/{{ unChecked }}
    </app-custom-checkbox>
  `,
  styles: [""]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  readonly checked = "Salary";
  readonly unChecked = "Hourly";

  formControl = new FormControl(this.unChecked, Validators.required);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
  }
}
```

**custom-checkbox.component.ts**

```
import { Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";

export const CHECKBOX_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomCheckboxComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: "app-custom-checkbox",
  template: `
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        [checked]="checkedValue === value"
        (change)="onChanged($event)"
        [disabled]="disabled"
      />
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </label>
  `,
  styles: [""],
  providers: [CHECKBOX_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CustomCheckboxComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input()
  checkedValue: string = "true";

  @Input()
  unCheckedValue: string = "false";

  value: string = this.unCheckedValue;

  onChange = (_: any) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};
  disabled = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onChanged(event) {
    const isChecked = event && event.target && event.target.checked;

    this.onChange(isChecked ? this.checkedValue : this.unCheckedValue);
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => {}): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => {}): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
}
```

Comment: @YouComeFirst how do you want to store the value internally. As `true | false` or as `Salary | Hourly`?